# How to find the sum of a geometric sequence with an upper bound of n

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I have an equation that includes the Sum, $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac12 (-5)^i$  where $n$ is the last term in the sequence.

We know that this sequence is geometric because the common difference is a multiple of $-5$ meaning that every term is multiplied by $-5$.

The sequence goes like:
$$\frac12, \frac{-5}{2}, \frac{25}2, \frac{-125}2, \ldots, n$$

My question is, how do we find the sum of this geometric sequence when the upper bound of the sigma notation is $n$? Is there some sort of formula that we can use in order to find the sum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean this serie $ \sum_{n=0}^{k} (-1)^n  \frac {5^n} 2 $ ? or $ k+ \sum_{n=0}^{k -1} (-1)^n  \frac {5^n} 2 $

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^i = a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

You can read more about geometric series at the [wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

While the formula I provided ends with $n-1$, it shouldn't be too difficult to modify it to a formula that ends with $n$.

Remark:

$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$ manes $a_0+ a_1 + \ldots +a_n$. It doesn't mean $a_0+a_1 + \ldots n$.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)

Let $$a + ar + a r^2 + a r^3 + \cdots + a r^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k= a \left(\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}\right)$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac12 (-5)^i = \frac12\,\frac{1-(-5)^{n+1}}{1-(-5)} = \frac{1-(-5)^{n+1}}{12}$$